# How to play google drive video using react-native-video?

Tags: javascript, react-native, video

I want to play a google drive video using react-native-video. I tried to pass drive video link as source, but it does’t load the video component.

Here is my code :

```
<Video
  controls={true}
  source={{ 
       uri:'https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/1ytSOrPtVExljEDqI5K9qQznYELMK13xj' 
         }}
  resizeMode={'contain'}
  style={styles.backgroundVideo} 
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to this site https://gdurl.com/ and paste your google drive video URL link there and get the permanent resource link. For e.g: *NMSaYT*

Then change your `uri` into this https://gdurl.com/NMSaYT will work for you.